# Sitecore: Server Error in '/' Application : Empty strings are not allowed. Parameter name: handleId

Tags: sitecore, workflow, sitecore8, sitecore-workflow

My regression testing is on going to an upgraded Sitecore instance of 8.0-U3 to 8.1-U2. And one piece of the testing is to check if the workflow is properly working as expected.

So I created a new sample item named PAGE ABC (template: `/sitecore/templates/Sample/Sample Item`) under the `/sitecore/content/home` node.

The workflow of the PAGE ABC is '**Sample workflow**' (template: `/sitecore/system/Workflows/Sample Workflow`) which was provided on a freshly installed Sitecore instance.

The PAGE ABC was created without any issue, but when I submitted the PAGE ABC, I encountered an ArgumentException shown below:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
________________________________________
Empty strings are not allowed.
Parameter name: handleId
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Empty strings are not allowed.
Parameter name: handleId

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[ArgumentException: Empty strings are not allowed.
Parameter name: handleId]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(String argument, String argumentName) +204
   Sitecore.Workflows.WorkflowUIHelper.ExtractFieldsFromFieldEditor(String handleId) +48
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Workflow.Run(ClientPipelineArgs args) +900

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline) +313
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.ResumePipeline() +224
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +825
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +197
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7763


________________________________________
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1073.0
```

**Note**: In this case, all the required fields are populated. I also tried leaving one (1) required field empty but same problem persist.

I searched for the keyword '**handleId**' parameter on the entire website and I found this section on my \temp folder _UpgradeHistory which I suspected has something to do with the above issue inside the **Sitecore.Kernel.xml**

```
   <member name="M:Sitecore.Workflows.WorkflowUIHelper.ExtractFieldsFromFieldEditor(System.String)">
        <summary>
        Extract the field values set by the field editor
        </summary>
        <param name="handleId">The Id of the handle holding the return values from the field editor</param>
        <returns>A NameValueCollection containg the fields</returns>
    </member>
```

I also tried searching over the internet, but I didn't find any relative solution to my problem.

**Edited:** I created a freshly instance of Sitecore v.8.1-U2. Replace the master db in the ConnectionString.config of the upgrade instance and the workflow submit action works, then I attached back the upgraded master database and I encountered again the issue.

**Edited:** I actually also noticed that there's a difference in the dialog box of the workflow. It is small compared to the working instance, which is a bigger dialog box. See supporting screenshots below:

**Figure 1** : Not working workflow

[image: Not working workflow]

**Figure 2** : Working workflow

[image: Working workflow]

I will post a more detailed investigation when I got new information. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem after upgrade. In my case clay tablet is installed in my sitecore and this error occur when I submit the CT3 work flow without adding comments in comment box. This is some thing related to custom workflow in my case. My sitecore version is 8.1-U1.

Comment: @marvin, When you inspect element, in the Network Tab, does the CommentEditor.aspx querystring "hdl" has a value? For example `/CommentEditor.aspx?hdl=8027C389F0DB4976909CB3981F9FDC7A`

Comment: @HishaamNamooya, The upgraded instance doesn't have the ?hdl querystring when I checked the network tab. I also checked the freshly installed 8.1-U2 instance and it was present. I also doubled checked the physical file located here: \sitecore\shell\Applications\Workbox and the CommentEditor.aspx for upgrading and fresh installed instance is identical.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat, I found the root cause and the fix, please see my answer below. Hope it resolves your issue, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix and the root cause.

First, I recreated the issue by creating a new workflow 'WORKFLOW ABC' under */sitecore/system/Workflows*, I added the necessary actions, such as Draft and Published, and then create a new template and assign the 'WORKFLOW ABC'. I also created an actual item and tried to change the workflow of the item from Submit to Published. The error appeared once again. (*successful replication of the issue*)

Then I did the same process to a freshly installed instance and I wasn't able to replicate the issue.

**Root cause:**

So I compared both values and there's a discrepancy, the **Default Comment Template field** was empty (*why it took me so long to figured this out*) but is existing to the freshly installed 8.1-U2 instance.

**Resolution:**

I changed the value of the Default Comment Template field from empty to **\Templates\System\Workflow\Standard Comment Template** and test again and it works.

**Screenshot for easy visualization:**
[image: Sample workflow with empty Default Comment Template field]

You may also want to update the **Default Comment Dialog Height** field value to 250, but this one is optional.

Comment: This is what i did to resolve the problem. But I am surprise that its by default empty in fresh instance of Sitecore.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat, Good to know that it works for you, as well. I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with the upgrade, I checked the freshly installed Sitecore v8.1-U2 and the fields were populated correctly.

Comment: I think its time to ask sitecore about this. :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. That field is not empty on any of the workflows on my instance. I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**
Since when changing the master database, the workflow works. Then the issue comes with the items. Can you check if the template of the workflow is the same as compared with the working instance.

Path is `/sitecore/templates/System/Workflow`

Comment: Thanks for helping. However, In my case, the problem relies on the database, I tried changing the master database to a fresh installed master database of 8.1-U2, and it works properly. I reverted back the master database and the problem is appearing again. I doubled check the DLLs and other files by using WinMerge and I don't see any faulty root cause there.